# Create shortcut to Google Location Accuracy setting on Nova Launcher

Tags: settings, location-services, nova-launcher

Is there a way I can make a shortcut on Nova Launcher so I can go straight to Google Location Accuracy setting other than go through a shortcut to location and hit Google Location Accuracy and Flipper switch?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Press and hold on free space on home screen. Then it will display three options, home settings, widget and wallpaper.
2. Tap on widget, and scroll down to select settings app icon, and drag it to home screen.
3. It will open a screen which ask for specific settings, select Location from it.

After that you can move to location settings just tap on that widget.

Comment: thanks that really helps me out but I needed to go straight still location accuracy (picture)because that's the GPS and I want to be able to turn off the GPS I after say I use Uber or something instead of going through all the settings and you know if you're in a hurry as you're probably geusing. I'm using law Nova launcher so maybe that might give you an idea of where I need to go I found one thing in the settings reset location actor see when I pressed it and creative the shortcut he just went straight to the location so yeah man

Comment: HUAWEI P20 LITE NOvA E3